# Laravel Fortify - enable Features dynamically

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

I want to toggle Fortify features based on user settings.

My `/config/fortify.php` has a basic set of features enabled by default:

```
'features' => [
    Features::resetPasswords(),
    Features::updateProfileInformation(),
    Features::updatePasswords(),
],
```

The remaining features are dynamically enabled based on database settings.

Here's my `AppServiceProvider::boot()` method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $features = (array)config('fortify.features');

    if (setting_bool('user_registration')) {
        $features[] = Features::registration();
    }

    if (setting_bool('verify_email')) {
        $features[] = Features::emailVerification();
    }

    if (setting_bool('two_factor')) {
        $features[] = Features::twoFactorAuthentication();
    }

    config()->set('fortify.features', $features);
}
```

The code works (features are enabled) when I visit the website.

However, the associated routes for these dynamically enabled features are not registered and do not show up in `artisan route:list`.

The `fortify/routes/routes.php` registers the routes only if the feature is enabled:

```
if (Features::enabled(Features::emailVerification())) {
  // register the associated routes ...
}

if (Features::enabled(Features::twoFactorAuthentication())) {
  ...
}
```

How do I generate routes for the dynamically enabled features?

---

Update #1: As suggested in the comments, I've included the code in `FortifyServiceProvider` class. The routes are not changed. I've also added the code to a middleware, still no luck.

It seems I need to inject this code before the `laravel/fortify` routing is configured. As of now, my code is executed after package initialization.

Comment: Try manually registering the fortify service provider in `config/app.php` after the `AppServiceProvider`

Comment: @apokryfos I've included the code in the `FortifyServiceProvider::boot()` method and included it in `config\app.php` immediately after `AppServiceProvider` but the routes still do not show up. Fortify routes are defined in the package, I need to execute my code before the package initializes it's routing table... I've also added the code in a middleware, still no luck - the routes are not registered.

Comment: If you published the `FortifyServiceProvider` then presumably you can run your code before `configureRoutes` is called?

Comment: @apokryfos I did include the code but no effect. I need to hook the code before the package is initialized at runtime